# PHP MYSQLi: Condition inside a php variable

Tags: php

I have a sucession of sql statements and while loops that display the topic information stored in a variable $topics, inside that variable there is a link to Delete the topic.

What I want to do is to make that link visible only to admin with a condition like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && (string) $_SESSION['level'] === "Administrator")
```

How can I do that? the link has to stay inside the variable because each topic has its own delete link next to it

this is the variable $topics, which is inside a while loop

```html
$topics .= "<tr><td><a id='del' href='deletetopic.php?del=$tid'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
```

for simplicity i removed other data that is displayed before the link in the same variable.

$topics is echo'ed later in the script

Edit: this is the actual variable

```html
$topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class ='post_info'>Posted by: ".getUsername($creator)." on ".convertDate($date)."</span></td><td align='center'>".topicReplies($cid, $tid)."</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td><td><a id='del' href='deletetopic.php?del=$tid'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Whats wrong with putting curly braces after the condition, then putting the `echo` of `$topics` inside that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && (string) $_SESSION['level'] === "Administrator") {
    $topics .= "<tr><td><a id='del' href='deletetopic.php?del=$tid'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
}
```

Maybe even split things out a bit more so that you get an empty table cell instead of nothing:

```
$topics .= "<tr><td>";

if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && (string) $_SESSION['level'] === "Administrator") {
    $topics .= "<a id='del' href='deletetopic.php?del=$tid'>Delete</a>";
}

$topics .= "</td></tr>";
```

**EDIT:**

This should work:

```
$topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class ='post_info'>Posted by: ".getUsername($creator)." on ".convertDate($date)."</span></td><td align='center'>".topicReplies($cid, $tid)."</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td><td>";

if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && (string) $_SESSION['level'] === "Administrator") {
    $topics .= "<a id='del' href='deletetopic.php?del=$tid'>Delete</a>";
}

$topics .= "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Yes but the variable contains many other data that I dont want to hide from the regular user, I just want to hide the link. Check the edit, I posted the actual variable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me it would just be:

```
 $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class ='post_info'>Posted by: ".getUsername($creator)." on ".convertDate($date)."</span></td><td align='center'>".topicReplies($cid, $tid)."</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td>";

if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && (string) $_SESSION['level'] === "Administrator"){
    $topics .= "<td><a id='del' href='deletetopic.php?del=$tid'>Delete</a></td>";
}else{
   $topics .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
 }
 $topics .= "</tr>";
```

This will append the information always appended, conditionally append the delete link and then finish the row with a `</tr>` regardless.

Comment: Check edit, I dont want to hide everything, just the link